# mod_rewrite que no elimine los parámetros de búsqueda en $_GET

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Tengo un sitio web que maneja URL amigables. En el .htaccess puse la regla así:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]*)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2&$3 [L,NC]
```

Así que una URL como esta:

```
http://localhost/legal/terms-of-use/
```

Funciona bien, el problema viene cuando quiero entrar a algo como esto:

```
http://localhost/legal/terms-of-use/?lang=fr
```

Ahí las cosas no funcionan como yo quiero, entra a la URL amigable bien, pero no me reconoce los datos que mando por `$_GET` ya sea ese o cualquier otro, con excepción de los datos ya puestos en el .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya le estás pasando parámetros de búsqueda en

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]*)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2&$3 [L,NC]
```

la regla elimina todos los parámetros previos.

Para evitarlo, hay que usar el flag [`[QSA]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) (*[query string append](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)*).

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)(?:/([a-z0-9\-]+))?/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Funciono!!!! Wow Gracias, estaba rompiéndome la cabeza xD
Según yo creía que tenia que añadir otro grupo en la regla algo como \?(.*) de hecho por eso tenia puesto el &$3. Ya lo corregí ¡De nuevo gracias!

Comment: @GabrielZapata Los parámetros de búsqueda tampoco aparecen en un `RewriteRule`... Si en el futuro quisieras verificarlos, sería en un `RewriteCond`, comparando con `%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: Con razón no los reconocía, por más que lo intentaba xD